# How to allow users to edit given string via $stdin in ruby

Tags: ruby, stdin, tty

I'm searching to allows users to edit an existing string.

```
Edit the following string: Edit me
# After user delete and add characters
Edit the following string: Edit you
```

I thought to prepend some data to the **$stdin** but seems like it's not possible and anyway IMHO it's a too radical solution.

Someone told me to use GNU Readline's Ruby wrapper so I've taken a quick look and I found `Readline#pre_input_hook` which acts before Readline start taking the input.

I tried:

```
require 'readline'
Readline.pre_input_hook = -> { "Edit me" }
result = Readline.readline("Edit the following string: ")
puts result
```

But seems not work.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to achieve here? What is the desired user experience (input/output)?

Comment: I want user can start from an existing input, so instead of type everything from scratch she already had an input to edit.

Comment: That's going to be very tricky to implement.... It's not how command line interfaces usually work. It's far more common to provide a default option (either a string, or within a list). For example, take a look at how [`tty-prompt`](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt) and [`highline`](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) work.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: @TomLord “That's going to be very tricky to implement”—the whole implementation (see below) took less than 20 LOCs. Managing 2M of requests per a minute is hard; command line is easy.

Comment: Your implementation is impressive. However, it is far from a perfect solution... What happens if the user tries to press arrow keys? Or if there are odd characters (e.g. `\b`) in something that gets copy+pasted? How about supporting windows line endings (`\r\n`), or multi-line input field? There is a good reason why CLIs do not usually work like this.

Comment: Yeah, @mudasobwa it isn't perfect, I took a look to `highline` and seems good for what I need to do. I think I'll use it.

Comment: @TomLord I am answering an exact question, not writing a library. Arrow keys are easy to clock as anything else non-valid, it’s just another `when`-clause. I am talking about the frustrating `leftpad`-syndrome we all are getting these days; I still think that developing is more about coding, than about copy-pasting and/or glueing 3rd party gems together.

Comment: @mudasobwa I appreciate that - I just felt this was perhaps a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); there is a much easier (no obscure edge cases to worry about) interface design, even if you choose to write it yourself rather than "glue a 3rd party gem" dependency onto the application :)

Comment: I am very sorry. I should explain the context since beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
begin
  system("stty raw -echo")
  print (acc = "Edit me: ")
  loop.each_with_object(acc) do |_,acc|
    sym = $stdin.getc
    case sym.ord
    when 13    # carriage return
      break acc
    when 127   # backspace
      print "\e[1D \e[1D"
      acc.slice!(acc.length - 1) if acc.length > 0
    else       # regular symbol
      print sym
      acc << sym
    end
  end
ensure
  system("stty -raw echo")
  puts
  puts "\e[0mEntered: |#{acc}|"
end
```

Here you go. More info on [terminal control sequences](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes). Also, [ANSI terminal codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I found `prompt.ask` from [`tty-prompt`](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt) fulfilled my need:

```sh
$ gem install tty-prompt

$ irb
```

```rb
irb(main):001:0> require "tty-prompt"
=> true

irb(main):002:0> prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
=> #<TTY::Prompt prefix="" quiet=false enabled_color=nil active_color=:green 
error_color=:red help_color=:bright_black input=#<IO:<ST...

irb(main):003:0> prompt.ask("What is your name?", default: ENV["USER"])
What is your name? xxx
=> "xxx"

irb(main):004:0> prompt.ask("What is your name?", value: "Mike")
What is your name? Michael
=> "Michael"
```